# Como hacer una copia se seguridad de una base de datos sqlite en android y restaurarla si el usuario cambia de dispositivo

Tags: android, sqlite

tengo una Base de datos sqlite en android studio y necesito crear una opción para el usuario de hacer una copia de seguridad que al momento de cambiar de dispositivo el usuario no pierda sus datos almacenados en sqlite, no tengo idea de como empezar, agradecería su ayuda!

Comment: Pues una opción de que el usuario tenga disponible una copia en cualquier dispositivo es crear un login y guardar los datos en un backend, por ejemplo con Firebase

Comment: algun tutorial de como hacerlo?

Comment: Uno de los codelabs de Google, ahí aprenderás qué puede hacer Firebase y cuando lo acabes, ya podrás implementar el backend en en tu app https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/?hl=es#0